# sum php multi dimensional array by index value

Tags: php

I have an array like this.

```
$dataListArray = array(
   array(0,3,0,0,0,0),
   array(0,0,1,0,0,0),
   array(0,0,0,1,0,0),
   array(0,0,0,0,1,0)
);
```

this data list array can have n number of index and each index array can have n number of data.  I am trying to sum the value of each index

```
$sumArray = array();
foreach ($dataListArray as $subArray) {
    foreach ($subArray as $key => $value) {
        $sumArray[$key]+= $value;
    }
}


// convert sum array as list
$dataList = implode(',', $sumArray);
```

This is doing sum as I want its output is 0,3,1,1,1,0

but it also giving me notice error

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/chart/1.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/chart/1.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/chart/1.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/chart/1.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/chart/1.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/chart/1.php on line 6

How to get rid of this undefined offset error?

Comment: You cannot add something to undefined variable. `$sumArray[$key]` __must be__ defined.

Comment: so how to define $sumArray[$key].

Answer (score 3):

You have to check if the `$key` is set by using `isset`. If not, assign 0.

`0` is needed to be initialized since you are doing `$sumArray[$key] += $value`, if the `$sumArray[$key]` is not set, You are adding the `$value` to an undefined.

```
$dataListArray = array(
   array(0,3,0,0,0,0),
   array(0,0,1,0,0,0),
   array(0,0,0,1,0,0),
   array(0,0,0,0,1,0)
);

$sumArray = array();
foreach ($dataListArray as $subArray) {
    foreach ($subArray as $key => $value) {
        if ( !isset( $sumArray[$key] ) ) $sumArray[$key] = 0; //Check if key exist. Assign 0 if not.
        $sumArray[$key]+= $value;
    }
}

$dataList = implode(',', $sumArray);
```

This will result to:

```
0,3,1,1,1,0
```

Doc: [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: It would be worth mentioning in your answer that this is because you are using `+=` and that requires the location to be initialised for it to work properly

Comment: I have another question @Eddie . If there is n index and and for every index there is n items in array. This will be right approach to sum .

Comment: @JaiSharma I don't understand :)

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution is fill `$sumArray` with zeros before use it.

```
$sumArray = array_fill(0, count($dataListArray[0]), 0);
```

Comment: You could create it using the size of the input array to be more flexible.

Comment: Ok. I will check. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looping over and adding the items up one at a time, you could use `array_sum()` to add each column  up at a time (using `array_column()` to extract the values to be added).

```
$dataListArray = array(
    array(0,3,0,0,0,0),
    array(0,0,1,0,0,0),
    array(0,0,0,1,0,0),
    array(0,0,0,0,1,0)
);

$sumArray = array();
foreach ( $dataListArray[0] as $key=>$entry )   {
    $sumArray[$key] = array_sum(array_column($dataListArray, $key));
}
print_r($sumArray);
```

Comment: Ok. Let me try it. Thank you.